# JPQL get difference in days between a column and now

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

I'm using hibernate and jpa in a spring boot application.
I have a hibernate entity with 2 columns, `type` (string) and `date` (LocalDate).

I want to select all the columns and the difference of days between my date column and now.

I succeeded in PostgreSQL: `select date, date - current date from table;`

I'm using an interface which extends JpaRepository. Until now i was successfully to insert new queries through `@Query` annotations. 
I can't figure it out how to select my columns and a column containing the difference of days in jpql.

Kind regards,

Comment: If you only need to select the date difference, why not simply write a java method that returns the difference from current time and your date column?

Comment: I need the old object in addition to the new column, difference between the date column and now. The complete picture is this: my angular frontend queries a spring backend using hibernate for a hibernate entity. I want to add to that hibernate entity a time column that shows the difference between the date column and now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can use query creator. You have to create a new entity which has the same columns as the original table and in addition the calculated difference between the date column and now. You have to be careful which date type is your column.

In my experience only Date from java.util can be used for differences with CURRENT_DATE (i may be wrong).

```
public List<NewEntity> getTest() {
String queryStr = "select new com.entity.NewEntity(n.type, n.date - CURRENT_DATE as 
time) from Table as n"
TypedQuery<PunteInspectieTimpRamas> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr, 
NewEntity.class);

return query.getResults()

}
```

Comment: It worked ! I created a new java class, TableExtra, which had 3 columns: type, date and time ( time is double, the difference between date and current date).

Comment: PS: After successful tests, i now get an error in intellij: PSQLException: bad value for type double: 15 days; - the difference is correct, 15, but untill now it just returned 15, not it returns 15 days. what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this with jpql.
But you can use your query as a native query, directly in you repository:

`@Query(value = "SELECT ... ", nativeQuery = true)
 ClassToReturn methodName();`

see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Yes, that was another solution i tried but with no success MyClass to return was the hibernate entity i was querying for. When i used my query i was trying to return my entity + a column in addition to the old object. i saw something similar here, not sure what to make of it https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_

Comment: You can not have a extra column in your select that is not mapped in your entity.
If you really want to have a property in your entity that is not in your database, you can add a `@Transient` property in your entity.


Then what you could do is :
return an `Object[]` (or a `List<Object[]>`) in the repository's method 
and manually instanciate an entity class and manually set the properties based on the columns.

But you lose most of the hibernate benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JPQL `day` function:

```
@Query("select day(date_column - current_date) from entity")
```